# Running one liner shell commands with interactive prompts or script in gitlab CI

Tags: linux, docker, shell, unix, gitlab-ci-runner

I need deploy some static site to survey.sh service, by following one-liner that works pretty well on my localhost from console and as script as well.

```
printf '%s\n' user@abcdefg.com somePassword  | surge --project ./public --domain domain_aka_domain_any_name.surge.sh
```

**surge** (npm package)- is interactive command that prompt for login/registering e-mail and then password.

- --project point existed directory with static website
- --domain create new sub-domain in space *.surge.sh

So by using printf it was successfully passed 2 answers on prompts from surge command on my host.
And it's output is here:

> Welcome to surge! (surge.sh)    Login (or create surge account) by
> entering email & password.
>
> ```
>       email: user01@abc.com
>    password:
> ```
>
> Running as user01@abc.com (Student)
>
> ```
>     project: ./public
>      domain: ciicicicdciqq.surge.sh
>      upload: [====================] 100% eta: 0.0s (66 files, 1699903 bytes)
>         CDN: [====================] 100%
>  encryption: *.surge.sh, surge.sh (366 days)
>          IP: 138.197.235.000
> ```
>
> Success! - Published to ciicicicdciqq.surge.sh

But when I use same one-liner or script.sh in .gitlab-ci.yml, on stage deploy like this:

```
deploy to surge:
  image: node
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install --global surge
    - printf '%s\n' user@abcdefg.com somePassword  | surge --project ./public --domain domain_aka_domain_any_name.surge.sh
```

it didn't work, and it's output limited to:

> Welcome to surge! (surge.sh)    Login (or create surge account) by
> entering email & password.
> email:        password:  Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01 Job succeeded

So, I assume that in docker container it's like interrupted on a second prompt (or may be even on first). Is it related to non-interactive shell or like that?
I tried **sh -c**  approach, but unlucky.
Need help and reference on explanation/man. Thanks

**EDIT, to clarify my question:**
What reason that Giitlab's/docker shell behavior different from my localhost and **how to solve it by shell/unix way**?. So, no matter it would be surge (I know about token possibility) command or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Surge provides a token mechanism for authenticating from CI providers like GitLab and using surge non-interactively.

First, you'll want to create a surge token. From your local system, use the command `surge token` to generate the token. Save this value.

In your GitLab project, open CI/CD settings and create two variables with their respective values:

- `SURGE_LOGIN` - the email address used for surge (this may actually be optional, based on my reading of [the source](https://github.com/sintaxi/surge/blob/878d9ca616693fcc4c6cb172ec67feaeb765ac25/lib/middleware/creds.js#L8-L11))
- `SURGE_TOKEN` - the token you just created using `surge token`

Then you can run your command (e.g. `surge --project ./public --domain domain_aka_domain_any_name.surge.sh`) and you won't be prompted for credentials.

```yaml
  script:
    - npm install --global surge
    - surge --project ./public --domain domain_aka_domain_any_name.surge.sh
```

Comment: I know about token possibility, but my question itself asks what reason that  Giitlab shell behavior different from my localhost. So, no matter it would be surge command or anything else. Thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: @LocalOps without looking deeper in the source, it's unclear to me why the first approach does not work. It is ultimately up to the application behavior and how it decides to read inputs. The differences that can cause different application behavior are numerous, but the most common would be that there is [no tty allocated](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2115) for user input and/or that the application detects the CI environment causing the application to change its behavior. It's also possible your password is wrong or needs escaping.